# Need to do concatenation list values to a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
word='p'

versions=['down','up','up+']
```

I was trying for the below output can any one help me please

```
pdown
pup
pup+
```

Please any one can suggest how to do ?

Comment: some people have already given you some code that will greatly help with this problem, however it would be very useful to us to be able to see what you've tried with a description about why that attempt isn't working for you.  Seeing that, we can help show you how to do it a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
" ".join("{}{}".format(word,x) for x in versions) 

pdown pup pup+
```

you want in new line:

```
print "\n".join("{}{}".format(word,x) for x in versions) 

pdown
pup
pup+
```

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for your answer


if we want in a new line 


pdown 


pup 


pup+

Comment: thanks the above code work well thanks a lot @Hackaholic

Answer (score 0):

```
' '.join([word + v for v in versions])
```

**EDIT:**

Since your edit now shows output words on different lines you can try:

```
for v in versions:
    print word + v
```

Comment: nit:  No need for a list-comprehension, `' '.join(word + v for v in versions)` would work just fine :-)

Comment: @mgilson list in join works better than generator expressions.List works faster in join.

Comment: @vks -- While that's true, it's only very _marginally_ faster (on CPython -- I've never seen timings for say PyPy) and, (since the speedups you gain will almost never be noticed by anyone using your program) I'd opt for the less visually jarring generator expression which may be noticed by future coders like myself :-).  It's what you use with most other builtins ... `any`, `all`, usually `sum`, etc.

Comment: @mgilson generator function creates a list in memory and so `join`has to wait before it can start its work.Whereas `on list` it starts working right away.But yes the timing wont be much to bother about :) though m not sure in case of long lists it might matter ..

Answer (score 0):

```
word='p'

versions=['down','up','up+']

for x in versions:
    print (word+x)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
pdown
pup
pup+
>>>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map

```
word='p'
versions=['down','up','up+']
word_versions = map(lambda x:word+x,versions)
print word_versions
```

This way you will have a list named word_versions containing what you want,you can print it or use it.